# Best way to smooth a jagged time series in ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, interpolation, smoothing

I'm trying to take a cyclic time series that looks like it jumps around a lot because of limited instrument resolution and smooth it to better illustrate the cyclic nature of the trend. I've tried tinkering with geom_smooth and spline-based interpolating of values, but nothing seems to do what I am after. The code below shows the series I'm trying to smooth out:

```
URL='https://nwis.waterdata.usgs.gov/nwis/uv?cb_00010=on&cb_00300=on&format=rdb&site_no=0317159760 &period=&begin_date=2020-07-01&end_date=2020-07-5'

f=read.delim(URL, comment.char = '#', stringsAsFactors = F)

f=f[-1,-c(1,2,4,6,8)]

colnames(f)=c('dateTime','temp','DO')

f$DO=as.numeric(f$DO); f$temp=as.numeric(f$temp)

f$dateTime=as.POSIXct(f$dateTime)

ggplot(f, aes(x=dateTime, y=DO))+

  geom_line()
```

[image: See this figure- not sure why it's not embedding in the webpage]

Any tips would be greatly appreciated, thanks!!